# I am trying to automate opening charts in Tradingview using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, tradingview-api

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
DRIVER = 'chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER)
driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/#signin")
driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys("Username")
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("Password")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Chart').click()
driver.find_element_by_class_name('input-3lfOzLDc').send_keys('SBIN')
time.sleep(20)
driver.quit()
```

Everything is working fine here but when I try to find element which needs to be change( the one sending SBIN  , I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tview.py", line 11, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='input-3lfOzLDc']").send_keys('SBIN')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@class='input-3lfOzLDc']"}
```

Can someone please help out

Comment: Also sometimes I get this error when it tries to perform click on Chart 
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=64222): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/89e453c4bc48f19f5190d13bcc46bf12/element (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10f6b1a90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))

Answer (score 0):

waiting a little bit longer works fine. I imported keys too because you had to clear that textbox

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
DRIVER = 'chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER)
driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/#signin")
driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys("sibyl666")
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("417305628m")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Chart').click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('input-3lfOzLDc').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
driver.find_element_by_class_name('input-3lfOzLDc').send_keys(Keys.DELETE);
driver.find_element_by_class_name('input-3lfOzLDc').send_keys('SBIN')
time.sleep(20)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Its not clearing the text for me 
Lets say it has BTC so it add up SBIN to it , BTC not gets cleared

Comment: i have no idea why it doesn't work but i tested it now and still works for me, can you copy all of my code and paste then try it again?

Answer (score 0):

this may be too late, but here it is what works for me. Basically, I use .clear() to get rid of the previous value and add some waiting times (depends on how fast the website loads on your machine).

```
ticker = driver.find_element_by_class_name('input-3lfOzLDc')
time.sleep(2)
ticker.clear()
time.sleep(2)
ticker.send_keys('SBIN')
time.sleep(2)
ticker.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```